# Can't listen TCP on local address with Android and NetworkComms.Net

Tags: android, xamarin, tcp, networkcomms.net

I'm trying to listen on TCP on my phone. I'm working with Android.Xamarin and NetworkComms.Net.
To listen, I use this on the server and it works:

```
 Connection.StartListening(ConnectionType.TCP, new IPEndPoint(IPAdresse.Any, 7878));
```

But on the phone, it doesn't. It open only on IPv6 address:

> Server listening for UDP connection on:  ::1:7878 
>   2607:fa48:6d6a:b421:11e5:620b:6b3:279e:7878
>   2607:fa48:6d6a:b421:62f1:89ff:fe1b:d52c:7878

When I try to put my own IP instead of IPAdresse.Any (smth like 192.168.0.172), NetworkComms tells me it cannot open a port on this EndPoint. I tried every port with a for and no one can be used...

I have Internet and Access Internet State permissions in the manifest.

Comment: When you hard code the IP (192.168.0.172), was your phone in the same network with it?

Comment: I didn't hard code it, I have a function that give me the current IP my phone use on the network